# Entity Framework 6: Change Sqlite to MSSQL/MySql in future without modify code?

Tags: entity-framework-6

The first, forgive me if the question is ... stupid.

I developing a winform app that use Entity Framewwork 6. Database now is Sqlite. In future, may be the database will change to MSSQL or MySql.

Is this possible ? If the anwser is yes, how I will do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: change the connectionstring in app.config

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for your reply. I know change connectionstring in app.config. But I don't want to change code ?

Comment: no, if you migrate the database model to the other DB with the same structure it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is possible. You just need the right data provider installed and the correct connection string configured.**

You can read about all the available providers as part of Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/providers/#which-providers-are-available-for-ef6)

**SQL Database (SQL, SQL Express and localdb)**

Included as part of EF6. All that is needed is a change in the connection string.

**MySql Database**

Requires a change in the connection string and the MySql.Data.MySqlClient provider. Further information on that can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-requirements)

**Sqlite**

If you are using Sqlite at the moment then you are currently using EF6 with the additional data provider System.Data.SQLite.